Using data aware scheduling to trigger downstream dags while using metadata contained in extra parameter as parameters for downstream dag
I currently have 2 DAGs that contain the same parameter that can be set called run_date. I want the upstream DAG to trigger the downstream DAG using inlet and outlet Datasets which seems intuitive. The issue I am running into is how do I feed into the downstream DAG the run_date param that was used in the upstream DAG. I was thinking this would be possible using the extra parameter within Dataset but haven't had any success with that.
The alternative that I  am thinking of is to use xcom push and xcom pull but that is not ideal because then I am adding tasks just to pass run-time parameters.
I am also aware of using an operator to trigger the downstream DAG that can pass parameters. The whole goal is to do this using data aware scheduling.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This is possible in two ways:

Having an entry in the params dict of the upstream DAG and then fetching the source_dag_run.conf in the downstream DAG from the triggering dataset events list.

In Airflow 2.10+ you can use the extra dictionary in the way you describe by adding information to it from within tasks. It has to be an @task / PythonOperator task or a custom operator though, so if that is possible for you without adding tasks depends on your setup.


The syntax is very similar so I put both in the examples below. If you are in a version before 2.10 you'll need to remove the 2.10 specific code from the t0 task for it to run. The other possibility should also work in older versions :)
Upstream DAG:
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.datasets import Dataset

my_dataset = Dataset("my_dataset")


@dag(
    start_date=None,
    schedule=None,
    catchup=False,
    params={"run_date_from_the_params": "2024-12-19"},  # the value retrieved in Option 1
)
def upstream():
    @task(
        outlets=[my_dataset],
    )
    def t0(**context):
        # ------ this only works in 2.10+ (for Option 2)
        run_date = "2024-12-23"
        context["outlet_events"][my_dataset].extra = {"run_date_via_extra": run_date}
        # ------- end of 2.10+ feature
        print("Done!")

    t0()


upstream()

Downstream DAG:
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.datasets import Dataset
from pendulum import datetime

my_dataset = Dataset("my_dataset")


@dag(
    start_date=datetime(2024, 12, 1),
    schedule=my_dataset,
    catchup=False,
)
def downstream():

    @task
    def t1(**context):
        triggering_dataset_events = context["triggering_dataset_events"]
        for dataset, dataset_list in triggering_dataset_events.items():

            # Option 1: getting the value directly from the source_dag_run.conf (run_date_from_the_params)
            print(
                "run_date_from_the_params is: ",
                dataset_list[0].source_dag_run.conf["run_date_from_the_params"],
            )

            # ------ Option 2: getting a value from the extra
            run_date_via_extra = dataset_list[0].extra["run_date_via_extra"]
            print("run_date_via_extra is: ", run_date_via_extra)
            # ------- end of Option 2

    t1()


downstream()


PS: If your downstream DAG needs the value in a traditional operator you can use a Jinja template.
For Option 1 something like:
bash_command="echo {{ (triggering_dataset_events.values() | first | first).source_dag_run.conf['run_date_from_the_params'] }} ", 

For Option 2 something like:
bash_command="echo {{ (triggering_dataset_events.values() | first | first).extra['run_date_via_extra'] }} ",

There are some more examples in this Astronomer guide.
I hope this helps :)

Thank you very much, this was very helpful.
